# Convert table to custom table result with some math operation

Tags: sql-server, select, filter

I am using SQL Server and I have one table generated I just need to create another table from the below generated table that will have the following details:

`Price` (total price of the repeated UserId)

`Number` (Unique number with respect to UserId)

`UserId` (unique)

[image]

**Please ignore first column it is repeated. Consider it as a one column i.e. only one data of 67.**

Comment: If you want me to write code for you, I will charge you my hourly rate (but if you need help fixing *your* code: tell us where you got stuck and I'm sure someone will help).

Comment: Please review [How to post a tsql question on a public forum](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) and [How-to-Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while I have read and got the solution.

It's simple

```
Select sum(Price) as Price, Number, u.UserId 
from the table Group by UserId, Number
```